# Who is Tatum referring to when she said "Cut, Casper. That's a wrap!" in Scream?

Tags: scream

In Scream (1996), as Tatum starts realizing the severity of the situation and that Ghostface isn't pulling a prank she says, "Cut, Casper. That's a wrap!"

What is the meaning behind this line? Is it referencing something/someone? Who is "Casper" here?

[Clip for reference](https://youtu.be/NdYmIIbYoH0)

Comment: Casper the friendly ghost https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_(film)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scream movie series is a satirical take on traditional horror and thriller movies. They contain many meta references to famous movies in those genres. So this is a direct reference to the character **Casper the ghost** from the [movie with the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112642/). Also, note that **Scream 1** came out in **1996**, just a year later after **Casper** the movie was released, so the reference is obvious.

Comment: Casper dates back to 1945 and is well-known from cartoons that are run on TV all the time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_the_Friendly_Ghost . The only reason that movie got made is because Casper is so well-known, not the other way around.

Comment: @BCdotWEB "that movie got made". Which movie are you talking about?

Comment: The one from 1995.